# Using mkStdGen from System.Random to generate random booleans

Tags: haskell, random

In the following program why does every single line return `True`? I would have thought that because I am initializing `mkStdGen` with different seeds, some of the lines should return `True` while other lines return `False` :

```
module Main where
import System.Random

main = do
  --why every single line prints "True" ?
  print $ fst (random (mkStdGen 1) :: (Bool, StdGen))
  print $ fst (random (mkStdGen 2) :: (Bool, StdGen))
  print $ fst (random (mkStdGen 3) :: (Bool, StdGen))
  print $ fst (random (mkStdGen 4) :: (Bool, StdGen))
  print $ fst (random (mkStdGen 5) :: (Bool, StdGen))
  print $ fst (random (mkStdGen 6) :: (Bool, StdGen))
  print $ fst (random (mkStdGen 7) :: (Bool, StdGen))
  print $ fst (random (mkStdGen 8) :: (Bool, StdGen))
  print $ fst (random (mkStdGen 9) :: (Bool, StdGen))
  print $ fst (random (mkStdGen 10) :: (Bool, StdGen))
```

Even in the source [mkStdGen](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.0.1.1/docs/src/System-Random.html#mkStdGen) it states that "**distinct arguments
    should be likely to produce distinct generators**" :

```
{- |
The function 'mkStdGen' provides an alternative way of producing an initial
generator, by mapping an 'Int' into a generator. Again, distinct arguments
should be likely to produce distinct generators.
-}
mkStdGen :: Int -> StdGen -- why not Integer ?
mkStdGen s = mkStdGen32 $ fromIntegral s
```

Comment: Interestingly, it's the first 53667 `Int`s that produce a `True` the first time (`length $ takeWhile id $ map fst . random . mkStdGen) [1..]`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interestingly this just came up on the haskell reddit ([discussion here](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/1yoxtk/nonrandomness_of_the_first_random_sample/)) and is documented in [this post](http://kenta.blogspot.co.nz/2014/02/rzzllapd-nonrandomness-of-first-random.html). The article suggests discarding the first generator from a seed, as in:

```
better_mkStdGen seed = snd $ randomR (1,6) $ mkStdGen seed
```

Or you could use a random package that makes some claims about the distribution, like [mwc-random](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mwc-random).

Comment: COme to think of it one should probably never ever use a random number generator that doesn't make promises about distribution or cryptographic properties unless your code is perfectly correct and performant with `const True`

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the article (which I had not seen) and the tip. It suggests using `tf-random` in the article.

Comment: Hi, it seems that discarding the first generator doesn't work for all situations. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/22128765/917635

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer, but I would definitely agree with jberryman and throw away the first several values, or use `mwc-random`.  You get a rather interesting pattern if you do

```
>>> :m +Control.Arrow +Data.List +System.Random
>>> let groups = group $ map (fst . random . mkStdGen) [0 .. maxBound] :: [Bool]
>>> map (head &&& length) groups
[(True,53668),(False,53668),(True,53668),(False,53669),(True,53668),(False,53668),
 (True,53669),(False,53668),(True,53668),(False,53669),(True,53668),(False,53668),
 (True,53668),(False,53669),(True,53668),(False,53668),(True,53669),(False,53668),
 (True,53668),(False,53669),(True,53668),(False,53668),(True,53669),(False,53668),
 (True,53668),(False,53668),(True,53669),(False,53668),(True,53668),(False,53669),
 (True,53668),(False,53668),(True,53669),(False,53668),(True,53668),(False,53668),
 (True,53669),(False,53668),(True,53668),(False,53669),(True,53668),(False,53668),
 (True,53669),(False,53668),(True,53668),(False,53669),(True,53668),(False,53668),
 (True,53668),(False,53669),(True,53668),(False,53668),(True,53669),(False,53668),
 (True,53668),(False,53669),(True,53668),(False,53668),(True,53669),(False,53668),
 (True,53668),(False,53668),(True,53669),(False,53668),(True,53668),(False,53669),
 (True,53668),(False,53668),(True,53669),(False,53668),(True,53668),(False,53668),
 (True,53669),(False,53668),(True,53668),(False,53669),(True,53668),(False,53668),
 (True,53669),(False,53668),(True,53668),(False,53669),(True,53668),(False,53668),
 (True,53668),(False,53669),(True,53668),(False,53668),(True,53669),(False,53668),
 (True,53668),(False,53669),(True,53668),(False,53668),(True,53668),(False,53669),
 (True,53668),(False,53668),(True,53669),(False,53668),(True,53668),(False,53669),
 (True,53668),(False,53668),(True,53669),(False,53668),(True,53668),(False,53668),
 (True,53669),(False,53668),(True,53668),(False,53669),(True,53668),(False,53668),
 (True,53669),(False,53668),(True,53668),(False,53669),(True,53668),(False,53668),
 (True,53668),(False,53669),(True,53668),(False,53668),(True,53669),(False,53668),
 (True,53668),(False,53669),(True,53668),(False,53668),(True,53668),(False,53669),
 ...
```

So it appears that there is a very definite pattern in these values.  All the groups have length 53668 or 53669, and it alternates between `True` and `False` for as long as I felt like letting that run.

If you throw away the first value:

```
>>> let r :: StdGen -> (Bool, StdGen); r = random
>>> map (head &&& length) $ group $ map (fst . r . snd . r . mkStdGen) [1 .. maxBound]
[(False,1),(True,2),(False,1),(True,1),(False,2),(True,1),
 (False,1),(True,2),(False,1),(True,1),(False,2),(True,1),
 (False,1),(True,2),(False,1),(True,1),(False,2),(True,1),
 (False,1),(True,2),(False,1),(True,1),(False,2),(True,1),
 (False,1),(True,2),(False,1),(True,1),(False,2),(True,1),
 (False,1),(True,2),(False,1),(True,1),(False,2),(True,1),
 (False,1),(True,2),(False,1),(True,1),(False,2),(True,1),
 (False,2),(True,1),(False,1),(True,2),(False,1),(True,1),
 (False,2),(True,1),(False,1),(True,2),(False,1),(True,1),
 (False,2),(True,1),(False,1),(True,2),(False,1),(True,1),
 (False,2),(True,1),(False,1),(True,2),(False,1),(True,1),
 (False,2),(True,1),(False,1),(True,2),(False,1),(True,1),
 (False,2),(True,1),(False,1),(True,2),(False,1),(True,1),
 (False,2),(True,1),(False,1),(True,2),(False,1),(True,2),
 (False,1),(True,1),(False,2),(True,1),(False,1),(True,2),
 (False,1),(True,1),(False,2),(True,1),(False,1),(True,2),
 ...
```

The fact that these alternate between `True` and `False` is simply because `group` works that way, it's nothing to be alarmed of.  Instead, notice that the number of values in each group is much smaller and harder to predict, although I think I can still see a pattern in it (look at how the 2s line up).  If you're going to use `System.Random`, you should probably make sure to generate several values before using one, or even better you could generate a random number of values before using it.

Comment: Thanks. I was playing around with `System.Random` because it is featured in "learnyouahaskell". Will give `mwc-random` and `tf-random` (which was featured in article quoted by jberryman) a try.

Comment: Hi, it seems that discarding the first few generators doesn't work for all situations. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/22128765/917635