# ghci memory increasing even with use of bang patterns

Tags: haskell, memory-management, stack-overflow, ghci

I tried to use bang patterns on part of the code in [Temporal correlations when employing System.Random (not present when employing System.Random.TF)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22128765/917635) in order to improve the memory consumption, but it seems that the ghci memory usage still increases at an alarming rate, despite the use of bang patterns. That is if I have the code :

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
module Main where
import System.Random

generateNthGenerator !startGen 0 = startGen
generateNthGenerator !startGen n = generateNthGenerator newGen (n-1)
  where newGen = snd $ ((random startGen) :: (Bool,StdGen)) 

main = do 
  print $ generateNthGenerator (mkStdGen 0) 10000000
```

Then upon loading this into ghci and running (by typing `main` in ghci) I find that the memory usage rapidly increases.

I have also observed that this memory increase happens evens for the following bang-patterned factorial code, albeit at a slower rate :

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
module Main where

getFactorialAcc 1 !acc = acc
getFactorialAcc n !acc = getFactorialAcc (n-1) (acc * n)

main = do 
  print $ getFactorialAcc 1000000 1
```

For this latter code the memory consumption initially stays at about 30MB (for about a minute) before suddenly starting to increase.

Comment: Have you tried to compile it with -O2?

Comment: @Yuuri Hi, when I compile with ghc the memory consumption seems fine. However with **ghci** memory consumption seems to blow up.

Comment: I have no explanation for your first example, but I suspect your factorial example just requires a lot of memory. `1000000!` has 5.5 million (decimal) digits.

Comment: Actually, I think the first one can be explained, too. You are forcing the `StdGen`, but actually if you look in `System.Random`'s source, you will see that the two fields of that type are lazy, so you aren't actually forcing them. You would probably be better off forcing that `Bool` you are generating each time. Also, it's kind of crazy that those fields are not strict. I would consider raising this as a bug report or something.

Comment: @JakeMcArthur Ah cool, what you said about the factorial code makes complete sense, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Jake McArthur (see comment above) the solution to containing the memory usage in the case of the random number generator is to write the code as :

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
module Main where
import System.Random

generateNthGenerator startGen 0 = startGen
generateNthGenerator startGen n = generateNthGenerator newGen (n-1)
  where randTuple = ((random startGen) :: (Bool,StdGen))
        !randBool = (fst randTuple)
        newGen = snd randTuple 

main = do 
  print $ generateNthGenerator (mkStdGen 0) 10000000
```

Alternatively one can do as Antal S-Z suggested below :

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
module Main where
import System.Random

generateNthGenerator startGen 0 = startGen
generateNthGenerator startGen n = generateNthGenerator newGen (n-1)
  where !(!_, newGen) = (random startGen) :: (Bool,StdGen)

main = do 
  print $ generateNthGenerator (mkStdGen 0) 10000000
```

Comment: You should be able to simplify this to `where (!_, newGen) = random startGen :: (Bool,StdGen)` (untested).

Comment: @AntalS-Z : Thanks I tried what you suggested but it still resulted in the memory exploding. However the following variant of your suggestion works : `where !(!_, newGen) = (random startGen) :: (Bool,StdGen)` where I have put an extra exclamation between `where` and the `(`